# Disable date-picker in ejs-calendar

Tags: html, angular, calendar, ejs, syncfusion

On clicking the month name in the normal ejs calendar, a grid system is displayed that offers to switch the month & year. I want to disable it.

```
<div id="container">
      <ejs-calendar
        #calendarObj
        [firstDayOfWeek]="1"
        dayHeaderFormat="narrow"
        (renderDayCell)="highlightWeekend($event)"
        [values]="date"
        [isMultiSelection]="isMultiSelection"
        [showTodayButton]="false"
        (created)="onCreated($event)"
        (change)="onClick($event)"
      >
      </ejs-calendar>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you link the calendar package that you are using?

Comment: @B45i https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/calendar/getting-started/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64567439?file=app.component.html  This used the same configuration in your question, but it doesn't have the Year/Month picker.

Comment: @B45i It does. Tap on the month name, you'll see the grid

Comment: @So You Just want to block the user from selecting another month and year ?

Comment: @B45i I guess, I have found a way. 

    pointer-events: none !important;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can disable any pointer events on title of the calendar.
Add this to your component.css file

`.e-title { pointer-events: none !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Set The [min] month as First-day current month and [max] as last day of the current month.

In component.ts file

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "app.component.html",
  providers: [ToolbarService, EditService, PageService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  today = new Date();
  firstDayOfMonth = new Date(
    this.today.getFullYear(),
    this.today.getMonth(),
    1
  );
  lastDayOfMonth = new Date(
    this.today.getFullYear(),
    this.today.getMonth() + 1,
    0
  );
  public ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

and in .template.html

```html
div id="container">
    <ejs-calendar
        #calendarObj
        [firstDayOfWeek]="1"
        dayHeaderFormat="narrow"
        (renderDayCell)="highlightWeekend($event)"
        [values]="date"
        [isMultiSelection]="isMultiSelection"
        [showTodayButton]="false"
        (created)="onCreated($event)"
        (change)="onClick($event)"
        start="month"
        [min]="firstDayOfMonth"
        [max]="lastDayOfMonth"
    >
    </ejs-calendar>
</div>
```

Example can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64567439?file=app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the title of the calendar using below css code.

```
  .e-calendar .e-header .e-title {
    pointer-events: none !important;
  }
```

Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-title-4eyzf1?file=app.component.css